# When performing leave-one-out cross-validation, why are my results seed dependent?

Tags: r, validation

For my homework, I am performing leave-one-out cross-validation using the *cv.glm* package.

Consider the following simplified example where the cross-validation estimates of prediction error are not equal:

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(100)
y = x - 2 * x^2 + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

model <- glm(y~poly(x, 2), data = df)

set.seed(1)
error_1 <- cv.glm(df, model)

set.seed(2)
error_2 <- cv.glm(df, model)

error_1$delta == error_2$delta
```

I understand that, when performing k-fold validation with *K =! number of observations*, random partitioning takes place. This would explain different values for `error_1` and `error_2`.

However, since I am not specifying *K*, it should be equal to the number of observations in *data* which should give the usual leave-one-out cross-validation.

To my understanding, leave-one-out cross-validation should not require a random element. Why are the results different? Where is a random number being used when performing leave-one-out cross-validation?

Comment: I don't have the  `cv.glm` package. However, using `caret`, LOOCV delivers the same delta.